# Do I need to use migrations for my schema or it's useless and I need to create everything on the fly?

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB and don't know about the best practices.

**So, my question is:**

Do I need to use migrations for my schema or it's useless and I need to create everything on the fly? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not only you don't need to create migrations, you can't.

Assuming you mean schema migrations. Data migrations are still useful/good idea.